# Сын жены брата

Tags: семантика

ответьте мне пожалуйста, у меня есть сестра у сестры есть муж у этого мужа есть брат у этого брата есть жена у этой жены есть сын от первого брака кто этот сын от первого брака приходится мне???

Answer (score 1):

А вам оно сильно надо? Не обижайтесь, пожалуйста, про такое родство (вернее - свойствО) обычно говорят "седьмая вода на киселе". Копаться в точных названиях  - надо иметь очень вескую причину.

Тем более, тут и ответа-то нет и быть не может. В терминах общей системы родства - никем. После расторжения брака между свойственниками (некровными родственниками по этому браку) остаются только отношения "отчим+мачеха" - "пасынок+падчерица". Строго говоря, даже они не являются родственными. Но даже это - не наш случай. Остальные же и вовсе теряются.

Так что упомянутый персонаж вам доводится ***пасынком брата зятя***. Или ***пасынком*** же, но ***деверя сестры***.  На выбор))). Подсказка: выбирайте второе, "зять" - термин неоднозначный.

В нормальном разговоре лучшее, что вы можете сделать - это описать ваши отношения именно так, как сделали в вопросе. По крайней мере можно при желании разобраться. А вот во всех этих шуринах-деверях-зятьях запутаться современному человеку, не знакомому с русскими патриархальными традициями, - это запросто.